# Three20 & Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, three20

I have got an app build using old Xcode don't know who is the developer...

I have fixed most of issues relinked the frameworks/libs

I am facing the issue below:

```
ld: framework not found InterfaceBuilderKit
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

I have spent 3 days on this but no success please help...

I have used the new three20 where as the version with old three20 I am able to run the app for testing i-e on simulator but when I build it for iOS device or do archiving I get lot of errors which are some thing starting from three20.h not found to some weird errors .....

Comment: The compiler can't find the InterfaceBuilderKit framework.

Answer (score 0):

if you're struggling with cryptic error messages, you can create a new fresh xcode project.  that's one way to solve it.

Create a new xcode project (keep the same app delegate name & project name), import three20, and copy over all your source files and resources.

I found that sometimes these old projects are just too messed up to fix (and a waste of time).

I also keep a bare three20 xcode sample project, which i use as a template (removed all nib files, modified plist file and etc)